# Area 51: Provide a "please vote on questions" type notice

Tags: feature-request, area-51, notifications, collaboration

I'm seeing one of the biggest problems with getting proposals off the ground is that almost nobody actually proposes questions or votes on existing ones; perhaps there should be a notification dialog asking users to contribute to the proposal?